Limit iOS share extension to access only screenshots
I want to build share extension for my iOS app that will be available only for the screenshots (stored in gallery and just created).
What is the right way to distinguish between screenshots and other images or photos?
Can I achieve it using Extension Activation Rules?
I see that SwiftUI component PhotoPicker is supporting matching param that can be set to screenshots. So I assume that system already has the info that some images are screenshots.
I found this question and answer it partially solves my task, but I'd prefer to limit share actions to screenshots only rather than making it available for all the images.
